# Compress a file into another file, with Gnu/Linux command line

Tags: compression, gzip

I am trying to take a file containing text, named `MyFile`, and compress it into a file named `MyFileComp`, within the same directory.

I have tried:

```
gzip MyFile | touch MyFileComp
gzip MyFile >> MyFileComp
```

Both commands create `MyFileComp`, but when I open the file it is empty. When I try to decompress the file, it says unknown suffix. I don't know what that means.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You'll find a `MyFile.gz` sitting next to `MyFile`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are not compressing it right.
Use -c to send it to stdout and add the ".gz" at the end. Is that the issue?

```
gzip -c MyFile > MyFileComp.gz
gzip -d MyFileComp.gz
```

Comment: This works better because when I use the commands without .gz I cannot decompress it without renaming it with the .gz extension. Unless there is another way.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `gzip` tool creates a file with the `.gz` filename suffix when compressing a file whose name is given on the command line.  Likewise, when decompressing a file with `gzip -d`, given the name of the compressed file on the command line, it expects to find a `.gz`  suffix at the end of the file's name, and will remove that suffix to create the filename of the uncompressed data.

If you don't want to adhere to this behaviour, i.e. you want your compressed files to not have a filename suffix at all, and you want to decompress these with `gzip -d`, then you can't give filenames on the command line to `gzip`.  Instead, let `gzip` read from standard input and write to standard output.

To compress:

```
gzip <my_file >my_compressed_file
```

To decompress:

```
gzip -d <my_compressed_file >my_file
```

Technically, you should use `-c` with both of the above commands, but since `gzip` is not given a filename on the command line, it will read from standard input and write to standard output anyway, and these streams are provided via the redirections.

Note also that with both commands above, the source data (whether it's the source for the compression command or for the decompression command) will be left in place, whereas if you use the `gzip` tool as one usually use it, by specifying the filename on the command line, the source file is usually removed, unless the `-k` (`--keep`) option is used.

---

Your command

```
gzip MyFile | touch MyFileComp
```

runs the two commands `gzip MyFile` and `touch MyFileComp` independently of each other.  No data is written to the pipe by `gzip`, and even if there was, `touch` would not read it.  What you end up with is a compressed file that is called `MyFile.gz` and an empty file called `MyFileComp` (assuming this file did not already exist). The file `MyFile` is removed.

Your command

```
gzip MyFile >> MyFileComp
```

compresses `MyFile` to `MyFile.gz` as before, and since `gzip` doesn't write anything to standard output, it will create the empty file `MyFileComp` (assuming this file did not already exist). The file `MyFile` is removed.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `gzip -c` will compress to `STDOUT`, so you can redirect it to any file name you want. The invert you are looking for is `zcat`, because `gzip -d` or `gunzip`, even if attempting to force with `-f` (as of 1.6), refuses to decompress a file without the `.gz`

```
gzip -c MyFile > MyFileComp
zcat MyFileComp > MyFile
```

**Warning**: This will overwrite `MyFile` if it already exists.